# In what circumstances does Windows accept '/' as a path separator?

Tags: windows, command-line, syntax, path

I prefer to use `/` rather than `\` as a path separator in Windows, as it doesn't need escaping in my C# source code, and I've read that modern Windows versions support both. However, it doesn't always seem to work.

The following works:

```
svnadmin hotcopy D:/foo D:/bar
```

but the following fails:

```
rmdir /s /q D:/bar
```

with this error:

> Invalid switch - "bar".

**In what circumstances does Windows accept '/' as a path separator?**

*Note*: No, I'm not going to use `Path.Combine` in all circumstances, since when a path such as `D:/foo` is hardcoded in my source, it's more readable as `D:/foo` than as `Path.Combine("D:/", "Foo")`. I *am* using `Path.Combine` in all other cases though.

Comment: The latter example is not Windows rejecting the path, its the rmdir utility which cannot disambiguate it with command line parameter. The Win32 API IO functions happily accept `/`, support thereafter is dependent upon the implementation of the thing that uses the path.

Comment: @AlexK.: But rmdir is part of Windows. That's why I'm asking what other parts of Windows have that problem.

Comment: @AlexK.: not all the API functions work either, and none of them do if you're using long paths.  Stefan, the bottom line is that there are lots of situations in which forward slash won't work.  My recommendation is that you forget about it and stick to the backslash.  You can use verbatim strings such as `@"c:\bar"` if you don't want to quote.